# Why does AWS IAM support SCIM 2.0 but not AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

While going through the AWS Cognito documents, I was unable to find SCIM support with the supported APIs. Could you please help in understanding if SCIM protocol is not required and why? and point me to relevant direction in case it is available with Cognito. Also, I could observe that scim apis are used with AWS IAM but not with Cognito. So is there a specific reason for the same?

Thanks in advance.